# Effective way to find multiple elements in selenium Test

Tags: java, selenium, automation

What is the best practice to get multiple names using selenium test. Consider I have the following columns in my page,

```
**ID NAME ADDRESS**

1   Anu   Addr1
2   ABU   Addr2 
3   Raj   Addr3
```

I have taken first name as

```
getWebDriverEx().findUIElement(By.xpath('id of name0')).getTeXT;
```

How do I get all name from above table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code,

```
WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.id("tableid"));
List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.xpath("tr"));
for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
  String name=rows.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("tr/td")).get(1).getText();
}
```

Note:I haven't compiled above code.